# Spring Resttemplate exchange method to call a PATCH request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

I have a Java 8 application with Spring framework. We need to call a patch operation using REST from our application.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
import com.xyz.myobject.ResponseAdmission;
import com.xyz.myobject.RequestAdmission;

@Repository
public class AdmissionRepository {

   @Autowired
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;
   
   public ResponseObject updateAdmission(RequestAdmission requestAdmission, String admissionId) {

   UriBuilder uriBuilder =  UriBuilder.fromUri("https://admissionportal.com").path("admission").path("admissionId="+admissionId);

   HttpEntity<RequestAdmission> admissionEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestAdmission, this.getHeaders);
   
   ResponseEntity<ResponseAdmission> responseEntity = this.restServiceESBSupport.exchange(uriBuilder.build(), HttpMethod.PATCH, admissionEntity , ResponseAdmission.class);
 
   return responseEntity.getBody();

}

public MultiValueMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Accept", "application/xml");
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        return headers;
    }

}
```

When I execute the above code, when the line with 'exchange' keyword is executed, it gives an error as:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.xyz.myobject.RequestAdmission] and content type [application/xml]

When I debugged the code, the restTemplate has the following 7 convertors registered:

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter,
StringHttpMessageConverter,
ResourceHttpMessageConverter,
SourceHttpMessageConverter,
AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter,
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter,
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
```

I also tried to add following line:

```
this.restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
```

But still not working.

**RequestAdmission and ResponseAdmission are the JAXB POJO objects generated from xsds.**

The webservice accepts the request in form of XML and response is also in form of XML.

Comment: For XMLs, you can use a simple String as the entity body and yo don't have to write any custom converters.

Comment: I do not want the output in String but the response object. here it is not able to convert the POJO into xml. Please mention the solution with the code changes.

Comment: I said that you can use a String as the http request entity body, not a response. Your error log shows that it cannot write the request, it mentions nothing of your response. So the issue is with the request.

Comment: So what changes need to be made in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own XML as a string and use it your request, like so:

```
@Repository
public class AdmissionRepository {

   @Autowired
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   public ResponseObject updateAdmission(RequestAdmission requestAdmission, String admissionId) {

   UriBuilder uriBuilder =  UriBuilder.fromUri("https://admissionportal.com").path("admission").path("admissionId="+admissionId);
   String xmlString = // create an actual valid XML string with all the <tag>value</tag> and the whole structure.
   HttpEntity<String> admissionEntity = new HttpEntity<>(xmlString, this.getHeaders);

   ResponseEntity<ResponseAdmission> responseEntity = this.restServiceESBSupport.exchange(uriBuilder.build(), HttpMethod.PATCH, admissionEntity , ResponseAdmission.class);

   return responseEntity.getBody();

}
```

Comment: In this case it is giving error : org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.String] and content type [application/xml],

Comment: No need to specify the content type in the headers. It will be recognized by the message format, just pass a valid xml.